# Swal behaving inappropriately

Tags: modal-dialog, alert, sweetalert, sweet.js

Whenever I click on OK button inside swal, then the main web page behind becomes unresponsive.

`````
<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
function myFunction(){
  swal({
  title: "About Murli!",
  text: "Select the Month or Year, or both and then click on the Search button to get the list.",
  icon: "info",
  button: {
    text: "OK",
    value: true,
    visible: true,
    className: "",
    closeModal: true,
    closeOnClickOutside: true,
    closeOnEsc: true,
  },
  timer: 3000,
});
}````

The alert box opens correctly but after clicking on OK, the main page becomes unresponsive.
`````

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({
  title: "About Murli!",
  text: "Select the Month or Year, or both and then click on the Search button to get the list.",
  icon: "info",
  button: {
    text: "OK",
    value: true,
    visible: true,
    className: "",
    closeModal: true,
    closeOnClickOutside: true,
    closeOnEsc: true,
  },
  timer: 3000,
}).done(function(){
    swal.close();
});
```

Try the above code.